# Syntax Error when calling Recursive Function inside a Recursive Function in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

The compiler returns a Syntax error when using the command in

```
xyz aux
    if((match4242 aux) = 0) then main (!list) else 1
```

Here's my full code.

```
open Printf
open Format

let regraUm m = m/2
  
let regraDois m = ((m / 10) mod 10) * (m mod 10)

let regraTres m = 42


let match4242 list =
    let a = ref 0 in
    let rec match42 list = 
    match list with
    |[]->[]
    |m::body->
    begin
    if (m = 42) then a := 1;
    match42 body
    end
    in match42 list;
    !a

let rec main aux = 
    let list = ref [] in
    let rec xyz aux = 
        let () = List.iter (fun x -> printf "%d " x) aux in
        match aux with
        |[]->[]
        |m::body -> 
        begin
        if ((m mod 2) = 0) then list := (m - (regraUm m))::!list;
        if ((m mod 3) = 0) || ((m mod 4) = 0) then 
            if (regraDois m <> 0) then
                list := (m - (regraDois m)) ::!list;
        if ((m mod 5) = 0) then list := (m - (regraTres m))::!list;
        xyz body
        end
    in xyz aux
    if((match4242 aux) = 0) then main (!list) else 1
```

The program checks if 42 is inside the list, if not then it calls itself again following a set of rules of division, subtraction, etc.
I don't know if this last info is helpful to debug this piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines:

```
   xyz aux
if ((match4242 aux) = 0) then main (!list) else 1
```

Represent a single expression, since they aren't separated by `;`. But indeed you can't have an `if` expression in this position (function argument) unless you parenthesize it.

Most likely you want `;` after `aux` here.